# Problems using setInterval and clearInterval more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm getting confused with what's happening here. The quiz works fine the first time. After the first play, though, I get all sorts of problems. I want to click the same button,"#start2", to start and also restart the quiz, ie clear the timer, put all variables back to 0 etc, and display the first question. As if the page had been refreshed, basically.

Instead, I'm getting faster ticking, the timer is incrementing on correct guess and so on. Horrible.

I've used modulo to measure how many times the "#start2" div is clicked. On first click, start timer. On second click - I want to reset the timer. Third click - start timer, and so on.

Any help is massively appreciated.

```
var n = 0;
var x = 0;
var p = 0;
var incTime;

function a(n) {
   var x,y,z;

    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
    if(x == 0){y = 1; z = 2}else if(x == 1){y = 0; z = 2}else{y = 0; z = 1}

    $("#question_holder2").text(questions[n].q);

    $(".answer_holder2").eq(x).text(questions[n].a).data('answer', 'a');
    $(".answer_holder2").eq(y).text(questions[n].b).data('answer', 'b');
    $(".answer_holder2").eq(z).text(questions[n].c).data('answer', 'c');
}

$(document).ready(function() {

//timing element
function startTimer(x){
    $("#start2").text(x);
}

$("#start2").click(function(){
    var setTimer;
    p++;
    //if it's been clicked before
    if(p%2 === 0){
        clearInterval(setTimer);
        $("#start2").text("Start");
        n = 0;
        x = 0;
        a(n);
        alert("okay");
    }else if(p%2 !== 0){
        //never been clicked before
        a(n);
        setTimer = setInterval(function(){startTimer(x=x+1)}, 1000);

        $('.answer_holder2').click(function() {
            //correct answer given
            if ($(this).data('answer') === 'a') {
                n++;
                if (n < questions.length) {
                    a(n);
                } else {
                    alert("End of quiz!");
                    clearInterval(setTimer);
                    $("#start2").text("You took " + x + " seconds, you     answered " + n + "            questions correctly, with - incorrect answers given.");
                    x = 0;
                    n = 0;
                    a(n);
                }
            }else{
                //incorrect answer given
                $(this).fadeTo(1000,0.4);
                var timeString = $("#start2").text();
                var incTime = (timeString * 1) + 5;
                $("#start2").text(incTime);
                startTimer(incTime);
                x = incTime;
            };      
        });
    };
});
});
```

Comment: You should be defining `setTimer` in the global scope with the vars at the top of your script.

Comment: @SeainMalkin Actually you should not define **anything** in global scope.

Comment: @freakish thats true, but since he has already defined a bunch of global vars and lacks some understanding of scope I decided to keep it simple.

Comment: @SeainMalkin I see your point. However in this scenario keeping `setTimer` local doesn't break anything. This is because new timer is supposed to be created each time you click `start`. Nothing's wrong with that.

Comment: @freakish If thats true then `clearInterval(setTimer)` is useless in the first if statement because `setTimer` will always be undefined. Which is probably causing his problem.

Comment: @SeainMalkin Yes, you're right. It seems to be an issue as well. The code *is* too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
$("#start2").click(function(){
    var setTimer;
    p++;
    //if it's been clicked before
    if(p%2 === 0){
        clearInterval(setTimer);
 //....
```

In this case, when you set to the `clearInterval` line, `setTimer` will *always* be 0, and not the id of a running timer. So this is not actually stopping any timer. If you don't stop the timer it will continue to run. So the function here:

```
setTimer = setInterval(function(){startTimer(x=x+1)}, 1000);
```

Will continue to run. So the next time you create a timer, you now have two timers updating `x` and it'll look like it's running faster.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var setTimer;
    $("#start2").click(function(){
        // the rest of your click handler code...    
    });

    //timing element
    function startTimer(x){
        $("#start2").text(x);
    }
}
```

Your `setTimer` variable needs to exist in a scope outside of your click handler. As you had it you were declaring a new variable every time so when you try and clear the timer, you are not actually clearing the timer.

Also: freakish's point about how you are reattaching the click handler is also a problem. You need to fix that too.

Comment: -1: Sorry, but you don't seem to understand how that code works. It creates a new timer each time `#start2` is clicked ( that's why it is called *start* ). I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: @freakish: the OP has `var setTimer`, then a couple of lines down (in the `if` clause`) they have `clearInterval(setTimer);`. This will not work. `setTimer` will always be 0 and not a running timer.

Comment: Ah, yes. +1 now. I've missed that `clearInterval` line. It doesn't make much sense in this scenario. The code is way to long. :)

Comment: @freakish: Agreed it's hard to read the code as it's structured here. But in my experience whenever somebody says ` I'm getting faster ticking`, it usually means they're not clearing a timer correctly (or at all).

Comment: Thanks for the help, all of you.
The script is now fixed. And whoever said I don't understand variable scope - you are right. For instance, if I say p = 0; p++. Every time I run the function, p = 0, so it'll never properly increment?  

If I declare it globally it works as intended. Also, x is used in 2 different functions. When I run function a, I am giving a value to x. This value is required later in my script. If I return a local x to use in another function - the value will be different due to Math.random()?

I will rewrite it soon, see if I can make some sense of it..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that bad things happen because of this:

```
$("#start2").click(function(){
    // some code...
    $('.answer_holder2').click(function() {
        // some code...
    });
});
```

When you click on `#start2` **new handler** is attached to `.answer_holder2`. So after for example 3 clicks, `.answer_holder2` has 3 handlers attached to it and when you click on it all 3 fire.

You're code is a bit complicated and I'm not going to give you a solution how to fix that. But I can give you a hint. Put inner `.click` outside of outer `.click`. You will have to change some code probably, but that has to be done.

**EDIT** What you could try ( as a fast fix, but not necessarly good ) is adding this:

```
$('.answer_holder2').off( "click" ).click(function() {
```

Additonally have a look at Matt's answer.